# Using a list to find and move specific files - python 2.7

Tags: python, list, csv, set

I've seen a lot of people asking questions about searching through folders and creating a list of files, but I haven't found anything that has helped me do the opposite.

I have a csv file with a list of files and their extensions (xxx0.laz, xxx1.laz, xxx2.laz, etc). I need to read through this list and then search through a folder for those files. Then I need to move those files to another folder.

So far, I've taken the csv and created a list. At first I was having trouble with the list. Each line had a "\n" at the end, so I removed those. From the only other example I've found... [[How do I find and move certain files based on a list in excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31029473/how-do-i-find-and-move-certain-files-based-on-a-list-in-excel]). So I created a set from the list. However, I'm not really sure why or if I need it.

So here's what I have:

```
id = open('file.csv','r')
list = list(id)
list_final = ''.join([item.rstrip('\n') for item in list])
unique_identifiers = set(list_final)

os.chdir(r'working_dir') # I set this as the folder to look through
destination_folder = 'folder_loc' # Folder to move files to
for identifier in unique_identifiers:
    for filename in glob.glob('%s_*' % identifier)"
        shutil.move(filename, destination_folder)
```

I've been wondering about this ('%s_*' % identifier) with the glob function. I haven't found any examples with this, perhaps that needs to be changed?

When I do all that, I don't get anything. No errors and no actual files moved...

Perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way, but that is the only thing I've found so far anywhere.

Comment: can you give real examples of what the csv contains?

Comment: You read in all the lines of the file, then you join them into a single line with all the filenames in it, then you create a set with a single item in it - that's not going to work. You (probably) don't need the set, and you don't need the `.join()`. Also you describe it as a CSV but you treat it in code as if it was just filenames in a list. Is the data comma-separated?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Yes, the csv is comma separated.

For example:
20131217_483500e_4217500n.laz, 20131217_483000e_4217500n.laz, 20131125_483500e_4217000n.laz, etc...

The other link I gave turns the list into a set, but I don't know why. The .join() was to get rid of the \n. When I wrote the list with line.split() and I tried stripping the \n off of each row in the list, but I kept getting errors like "line.strip()" it claims line is not defined. Or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its really not hard:

```
for fname in open("my_file.csv").read().split(","):
    shutil.move(fname.strip(),dest_dir)
```

you dont need a whole lot of things ...

also if you just want all the *.laz files in a source directory you dont need a csv at all ...

```
for fname in glob.glob(os.path.join(src_dir,"*.laz")):
    shutil.move(fname,dest_dir)
```

Comment: I haven't been able to get it to work yet... How do I set up the folder to be searched through? Do I simply set it as the working directory and put the csv in there? When I tried using the csv in another folder, I kept getting an error saying it was an invalid mode ('r') or filename. So I put it in the same folder and don't get that error, but I keep getting a TypeError: must be (buffer overflow), not str.

Comment: Thank you very much, we were finally able to get it to work. One of the things I noticed is that the list I had needed to be manipulated for it to work. If I included files that may be in other folders, it would get hung up and claim the file or directory doesn't exist. But thank you for your help.